xEventGroupSync blocks other tasks
On a Cortex M4 with FreeRTOS I have three tasks.
Each task has a init part and a for (;;) infinite loop.
I want to syncronize the tasks so that the infinite loops starts only after all the tasks have performed their init parts.
I used the xEventGroupSync as described in the freertos documentation.
It happens that the first xEventGroupSync call stops the execution of the other two tasks so that they never reach the sync point.
Also the timeout given in the last parameter of the xEventGroupSync function does not work and the function never exits.
